# typeof(BindingExpression).GetProperty() return null in .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am using WPF application and i done my validations on controls based on the below code.

```
var targetProperty = typeof(BindingExpression).GetProperty("TargetProperty",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(value, null) as DependencyProperty;
```

It is working fine in framework 4.0.

But if i am installing framework 4.5,the above code will not work because

```
typeof(BindingExpression).GetProperty("TargetProperty",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic) is null.
```

Why this behavior based on different version of framework? Is there any change in the above method.

Sreyas MN

Comment: First [`BindingExpressionBase.TargetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpressionbase.targetproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) is `public` so you should use `BindingFlags.Public` second, according to MSDN, it's new to .NET 4.5 so how it was working in .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN documentation says the exact opposite: In [.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpressionbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `BindingExpressionBase`, which `BindingExpression` inherits from, has a property called [`TargetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpressionbase.targetproperty.aspx), but not in [.NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpressionbase%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Are you sure it's not the other way around? It seems like the property was added, or at least made public in .NET 4.5.

Maybe you should change the `BindingFlags` for .NET 4.5 to `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public` instead, it could be done with a quick `#ifdef`.

Anyway, it's never a good idea to rely on private properties (or any private member) across versions of the .NET framework.